# how to compile ruby and python in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: python, ruby

I've recently immigrated to Ubuntu and I don't know that much about it.i would be thankful if you could tell me step by step how to add ruby and python to Ubuntu 14.10. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Python comes as an inbuilt package in Ubuntu. To run a Python script, open up your terminal and change to the directory where you have your Python code.

Now type:

`python <your_filename>.py`

To run Ruby code, you need to install the Ruby package. To install it, type the following code in the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install ruby`

After installing, to check if Ruby is installed correctly,type:

`ruby - v`

If this shows your Ruby version, you have successfully installed Ruby.

To run Ruby code, type :

`ruby <your_filename>.rb`